# LocalDateTime gets added the amount of UTC offset while JPA saving

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using mysql and my column name in the entity is stored in the form of DATETIME.
I have an entity: (Base Entity has createdAt and updatedAt in the form of LocalDateTime)

```
    @Builder
    @Data
    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
    public class ExampleEntity extends BaseEntity {
    
        private LocalDateTime timeToSave;
}
```

and I have an object like

```
    public class SomeObject {
        private LocalDateTime timeWhichIsToBeSaved;
}
```

While I am trying to save,

```
example = ExampleEntity.builder().timeToSave(someObject.gettimeWhichIsToBeSaved());
exampleRepository.save(example);
```

The time gets added by 5 hours 30 mins, which I reckon is the UTC offset amount, I live in UTC+5:30. The createdAt and updatedAt is at my current time.

Comment: Can't you use an `OffsetDateTime` instead and define the offset to be used?

Comment: Which database are you using, and what is the data type of the database column?  Most databases give you a choice of storing a UTC time, or storing a "local" time.  It may be that the type of the column doesn't match the type that you're trying to read it into.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am using mysql and my column data type is DATETIME.

Comment: OK, that's good.  The DATETIME type corresponds to a LocalDateTime.  The question is then, what happens to the value before it gets saved.  You should probably step through this with your debugger, to see the actual value of `timeWhichIsToBeSaved` and `timeToSave` at each point in the process, both saving and retrieving.  The problem is not in the code you've shown here.

Comment: JDBC doesn't understand or have a LocalDateTime, so the statements generated have to convert it into a long (java.util.Date/java.sql.Timestamp) to pass it to the database. This process is likely your issue - check Hibernate and its docs if you want different behavior in a LocalDateTime->DateTime. Also note MYSQL DATETIME is pretty much a numeric long with no timezone, so the long value is pretty much universally a UTC value that then gets converted based on timezones being applied.